# Third Dropdown Is Influenced On First And Second Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Please note that I got this script from another question on this website and I want to use it towards my project. What I am trying to accomplish is if English and The Indian Express is selected then it will show the third dropdown a list of pages to go to. If the Hindu is selected then a different set of pages will appear in the third dropdown.
Here is what I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

function SetMedia(objLanguage) {
    var objMedia = document.getElementById("media");
    objMedia.options.length = 0;
        objMedia.disabled = false;
switch (objLanguage.value) {
    case "English":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Indian Express"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Hindu"));
    break;
case "Tamil":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Tamil Paper 1"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Tamil Paper 2"));
    break;
case "Telugu":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Telugu Paper 1"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Telugu Paper 2"));
    break;
default:
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("select"));
    objMedia.disabled = true;
    break;
}

}
function Setpage(objLanguage) {
var objMedia = document.getElementById("page");
objMedia.options.length = 0;
    objMedia.disabled = false;
switch (objLanguage.value) {
case "The Hindu":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Page 32"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Page 36"));
    break;
case "The Indian Express":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Page 40"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Page 65"));
    break;
default:
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("select"));
    objMedia.disabled = true;
    break;
}

}
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<select name="language" id="language" onchange="SetMedia(this)">
<option>select</option>
<option >English</option>
<option>Tamil</option>
<option>Telugu</option>
</select>

<select name="media" id="media" disabled="disabled">
<option>select</option>
</select>
<select name="page" id="page" onchange="Setpage"disabled="disabled">
<option>select</option>
</select>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set `onchange="Setpage"` for:

```
<select name="media" id="media" disabled="disabled">
```

like so:

```
<select name="media" id="media" onchange="Setpage(this)" disabled="disabled">
```

Also be sure to set `disabled` to `false` in that function as well:

```
function SetMedia(objLanguage) {
    var objMedia = document.getElementById("media");
    objMedia.options.length = 0;
        objMedia.disabled = false;
switch (objLanguage.value) {
    case "English":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("choose"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Indian Express"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Hindu"));
    break;
case "Tamil":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Tamil Paper 1"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Tamil Paper 2"));
    break;
case "Telugu":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Telugu Paper 1"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Telugu Paper 2"));
    break;
default:
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("select"));
    objMedia.disabled = true;
    break;
}

}
function Setpage(objLanguage) {
var objMedia = document.getElementById("page");
objMedia.options.length = 0;
    objMedia.disabled = false;
switch (objLanguage.value) {
case "The Hindu":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Option 3"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Option 4"));
    break;
case "The Indian Express":
    objMedia.disabled = false;
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Option 1"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Option 2"));
    break;
default:
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("select"));
    objMedia.disabled = true;
    break;
}

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxLsLqmg/)

Comment: Thank you. Since I am a newbie of this site, can I create a second question or can I ask it here?

Comment: @hyperj123 I would post a new question. It could help people in the future too

Comment: I did find an issue with the script. My second box is always the same characters. Minor, Moderate, and Severe. How can I get it so that if for instance someone selects uniform > minor > "not wearing hat while handling product" but say they change uniform to sanitary > minor, it will still display "not wearing hat while handling product" How do I avoid this? Based on my list of incidents there are severity levels and based on those levels are an array of options.